# Как сделан переход на посты в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я ради понимания и всего такого решил написать простенькую CMS, для примера я взял Wordpress, поставил тему Twenty Seventeen из стардартных и там я заметил что при переходе на созданную запись уже на сайте в URL прописано "http://wordpress/2020/08/19/привіт-світ/". Как сдеалан переход по дате и названию если такой папки нет и не было?

Comment: это называется маршрутизация (роутинг). нужна для вывода человекопонятных адресов. входящий адрес разбирается по фрагментам, далее стандартный модуль по правилам из конфига выбирает обработчик. думаю, специалисты по wordpress подскажут конкретно, где чего искать.

Comment: В wp есть настройка, какую запись показывать на главной странице. Ядро и редиректит.

Comment: Перед тем как писать свою CMS лучше прочитайте раздел "Get started" любого из фреймворков)

Comment: WP Punk - только хардкор для полного понимания работы системы)

Answer (score 1):

Формирование ЧПУ(Seo-frendly URL) - "Человекопонятный URL" - в WordPress производится в настройках административной части сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]